# Sorting the multiselect entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I try to sort some custom entities which come from a `multiselect` query:

```
criteria = builder.createQuery();
chat = criteria.from(ChatModel.class);

criteria.multiselect(
   builder.construct(
      ChatInfo.class,
      chat.alias("chat"),
      builder.max(
          builder.coalesce(
              messages.get("created"),
              chat.get("created")
          )
      ).alias("lastActivity"))
  .groupBy(query.getChat())
  .orderBy(builder.asc(builder.literal("lastActivity")))
```

I need to sort the result by `lastActivity` field which has actually `ChatInfo`'s attribute. I tried using an alias.

But it doesn't work. There are no errors.

Comment: Have you tried `.orderBy(builder.asc(chat.get("lastActivity")))`?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos `lastActivity` is part of ChatInfo, not ChatModel

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. I guess you have to repeat the "lastActivity" expression in the `orderBy`, e.g. as: `.orderBy(builder.asc(builder.max(builder.coalesce(...))))`.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos thanks, but doesn't work as well